# Is there a way to schedule Automatic Source Code and Database Backups?

Tags: backups

A colleague told me about a plugin that he used to run on Word Press that would save his Source Code and DB automatically. He asked me to look into any plugins like this for Drupal 6.x and 7.x.

Does anyone have any experience with this that they can share?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks mixerowsky and Jance. I believe we have this installed on the site and when I check in the folder is supposed to be saving to it only shows me an HTACCESS file that says "order allow,deny
deny from all" and a test.txt file that says "this file should not be publicly accessible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module. It is available for both, Drupal 6 and 7.

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or
>   migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip,
>   bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.